# Measuring Cup for Batch Sparging?

Tags: all-grain, sparge, batch-sparge

What do people like in terms of heat resistant measuring cups for batch sparging? I found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001PZ9M8U) one on Amazon. I was wondering if there were other options that were better.

I'm using it for re-circulation of the wort. I also was thinking of using it to add in the hot water for subsequent sparges after fully drained the lauter tun.

Comment: What are you using this measuring cup for?

Comment: I'd guess the measuring cup is for draining wort into for re-circulation.

Answer (score 1):

For vorlauf and xferring water, I use a 2 qt. plastic pitcher which you can see below.  I also use a 2 cup Pyrex measuring cup for pulling gravity and pH samples.

[image: Denny's equipment]

Answer (score 0):

I just use a regular pyrex glass one.  I wouldn't want to use metal, because I sometimes put it in the microwave to bring the mash temp up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I just use a 2 qt rubbermaid pitcher. Seems to do just fine for re-circulation wort.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite recent purchases was a large heat-tolerant gallon pitcher like [this one at Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BC5GME). Marked at 1/8 gallon (1/2 qt) for measuring and useful for vorlaufing, too.

Answer (score 0):

HomeBrewFinds is one of my favorite sites for finding equipment like this. They track prices over time. One of the pages is a list of low-cost items to add to your Amazon purchase to get to $25 and qualify for cheap shipping.  That page is [here](http://www.homebrewfinds.com/p/homebrewing-related-amazon-fillers.html) and contains several nice options including some aluminum restaurant quality pitchers for under $10.